# Failed template argument deduction with partially specialised template using 'auto'

Tags: c++

For a bit of fun, I created a very basic compile-time type-value map class, as follows:

```cpp
template <typename T, auto V>
struct TypeValuePair { };

template <typename... TypeValuePairs>
struct TypeValueMap
  {
  struct MapItems : TypeValuePairs... { };

  template <typename T, auto V>
  static constexpr auto Lookup(TypeValuePair<T, V>*)
    { return V; }

  template <auto V, typename T>
  static T Lookup(TypeValuePair<T, V>*);

  template <typename T>
  static constexpr auto ValueFor = Lookup<T>((MapItems*)nullptr);

  template <auto V>
  using TypeFor = decltype(Lookup<V>((MapItems*)nullptr));
  };
```

to be used in a way such as this:

```cpp
struct A; struct B; struct C;
enum class Values { A, B, C };

using Map = TypeValueMap<
                TypeValuePair<A, Values::A>,
                TypeValuePair<B, Values::B>,
                TypeValuePair<C, Values::C>,
                TypeValuePair<struct Other, 0>
              >;

static_assert(Map::ValueFor<A> == Values::A, "");
static_assert(Map::ValueFor<B> == Values::B, "");
static_assert(Map::ValueFor<C> == Values::C, "");
static_assert(Map::ValueFor<struct Other> == 0, "");

static_assert(std::is_same<Map::TypeFor<Values::A>, A>::value, "");     //***
static_assert(std::is_same<Map::TypeFor<Values::B>, B>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<Map::TypeFor<Values::C>, C>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<Map::TypeFor<0>, struct Other>::value, "");  //***
```

Unfortunately, the two lines marked `//***` fail with the error *failed template argument deduction* or similar on clang and g++ (the two compilers I have to hand).  I can understand why this might be because `Values::A` has the value `0` so the two potentially collide.  However, I would argue that they are in fact different types – one is plain integer, the other an `enum class` with underlying type integer – and so shouldn't in fact collide.

If I implement my map class differently, like so:

```cpp
template <typename T, auto V>
struct TypeValuePair
  {
  protected:
  static constexpr auto Lookup(T*)
    { return V; }

  template <template <auto> class Wrapper>
  static T Lookup(Wrapper<V>*);
  };

template <typename... TypeValuePairs>
struct TypeValueMap
  {
  struct MapItems : TypeValuePairs...
    { using TypeValuePairs::Lookup...; };

  template <auto> struct LookupByValue;

  template <typename T>
  static constexpr auto ValueFor = MapItems::Lookup((T*)nullptr);

  template <auto V>
  using TypeFor = decltype(MapItems::Lookup((LookupByValue<V>*)nullptr));
  };
```

then there are no template argument deduction errors.

Therefore the question is, is the failure to deduce the template argument in the first implementation due to a bug in the compilers (given my assertion that integer and `enum class` should be treated as different types and not collide) or is it a misunderstanding on my side of what is possible with template argument deduction (I am not a language lawyer!), or some other bug in my implementation?

Comment: Unrelated to the main question, but you can simplify: `struct MapItems : TypeValuePairs... { using TypeValuePairs::Lookup...; };`.

Comment: Are you sure clang and gcc produce the same error? What happens with both compilers if you remove A from the map?

Comment: Thanks @Evg for the suggestion, that's really neat!  I've updated the question with this change.

Comment: @n.m. - yes, both compilers produce the same error; if your remove A from the map the "ambiguity" goes and the remaining map resolves

Comment: Minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/nIFKxY

Comment: @n.m., it looks like both compilers implicitly convert `enum class` to the underlying type. If `A` is replaced with `A = 1`, everything works as expected.

Comment: @Evg, it isn't that it implicitly converts to the underlying type because you can do `enum class : unsigned` and it still gives the error.  It seems it does a direct match on the numerical value.  Given your minimal example, I am increasingly inclined towards the "compiler bug" explanation...

Comment: If it were implicitly converted to the underlying type, this error would be pretty much expected, because `TypeValueMap<TypeValuePair<Foo, 0u>, TypeValuePair<Other, 0>>` gives an error, too, although `0` and `0u` are of different types.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Values::A` is convertible to `0` by means of a "converted constant expression".

From the C++14 standard ([n4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/raw/master/papers/n4140.pdf) section 5.19, paragraph 3, page 133):

> A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to a prvalue of type T, where the converted expression is a core constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only user-defined conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (4.1), integral promotions (4.5), and integral conversions (4.7) other than narrowing conversions (8.5.4).
>
> [ Note: such expressions may be used in new expressions (5.3.4), as case expressions (6.4.2), as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is fixed (7.2), as array bounds (8.3.4), and as **integral or enumeration non-type template arguments** (14.3). —end note ]

(my emphasis)

The effect is that there is an overload ambiguity between `0` and `Values::A`.

Comment: Is this correct, however, when performing ambiguity checks with an 'auto' non-type template argument?  Why does the compiler need to make a converted constant expression out of it, if no conversion is strictly necessary?